# How can I use one component (page) for multiple route in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

As you all know Next JS doesn't have any route, I am trying to build a web app in next JS in which I have to use the same component for multiple routes without copy pasting in to different directory.

**Directroy structure:**

```
src
    pages
        new (AddListComponent)
        edit-[id] (AddListComponent)
```

**AddListComponent**

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'

class Listing extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        }
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>This is my new component</div>
        )
    }
}
export default withRouter(Listing)
```

Comment: Have a look at https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes.

Answer (score 15):

Inside the route directory you can import and export the component from another directory.

Inside your second route /myPage2/index.js :

```
import MyPage from ../myPage.js
export default MyPage
```

Comment: I would like to know how to do it when we have dynamic routes

Answer (score 11):

You can create a page with ***optional*** parameters.

```
pages
 ┣ tasks
 ┃ ┣ manage
 ┃ ┃ ┗ [[...id]].jsx
 ┃ ┣ index.jsx
 ┃ ┗ service.js
 ┣ _app.jsx
 ┣ dashboard.jsx
 ┣ index.jsx
 ┗ login.jsx
```

`/tasks/manage` and `tasks/manage/14` will route the same component `[[...id]].jsx`

- Do not forget to use  double brackets and three dots.
  `[[...foo]].jsx`

> Catch all routes can be made optional by including the parameter in
> double brackets ([[...slug]]).
>
> For example, pages/post/[[...slug]].js will match /post, /post/a,
> /post/a/b, and so on.

Please [check](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

[NextResponse.rewrite](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) is one way to reuse components among different routes.

This feature allows us to map a route to another. It retains parameters from the requested route for use in the resolved route as well.

Your example has two routes: 
`/new` 
`/edit-[id]`

Including the `rewrites` function in `next.config.js` as below will route requests from `/edit-[id]` to `/new` and will populate the `router.query.id` parameter as expected. We don't even need to define `@/pages/edit-[id].jsx`

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  ...other next config parameters...
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/edit-:id",
        destination: "/new"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
// @pages/new.jsx
// the configuration above means this component will be used as though @pages/edit-[id].jsx uses this same file.
import { NextRouter, withRouter } from 'next/router'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import React from 'react'
  
class EditForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render () {
    
        const id = this.props.router.query.id ?? "empty"
        return (
            <div>path id param: {id}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(EditForm)
```

```
// files
/pages/new.jsx
/next.config.js
```

#### Usage

1. Empty form, no id provided 
   localhost/new

```
path id param: no id
```

2. Populated for, with an id 
   localhost/edit-something

```
path id param: something
```